# Open a port on google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, port, google-cloud-compute-engine

Could not open port on GCP Compute Engine VM instance

Hi,

I need to open port 5000 on my GCP instance. Tried doing that by adding a firewall policy opening all ports to the region. See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlpS4.png)

Didn't work, pinged the port and it is still closed.

Port 5000 closed

```
% telnet <ip_address> 5000
Trying <ip_address>...
telnet: connect to address <ip_address>: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Port 22 works

```
% telnet <ip_address> 22
Trying <ip address>...
Connected to <ip address>.bc.googleusercontent.com.
```

What else do I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello there! Are you sure something is listening on port 5000? What error do you get? Timeout?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error is: unable to connect to remote host. 

I am running the code with a docker container with network_mode="host"

Do I have to specify something else in the firewall / docker compose file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved and the port is open! I didn't do anything else, the configs were fine. Maybe a delay / cache somewhere.

Thanks @armando-cuevas